# Can I use a Harris vinbrite to filter cider

Tags: cider

[image]

Can I filter this cider with a Harris vinbrite filter

Answer (score 2):

In theory, Yes you can, I have not used the Vinbrite filters. but its made for wine and spirits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is not really any difference between wine and cider when it comes to filtering. Just make sure you settle your cider a few weeks before filtering so you don't clog the filter. The cider should be pretty clear before you send it through the filter.